# Upgrades of the stable and their effects on the magical horse

Tags: secret-of-the-magic-crystals

In "Secret of the Magic Crystals", I can buy new equipment for the stable. But I don't understand how it affects the magical horse. Since the upgrades are so expensive, there has to be an explanation. What are the effects of the equipment and its upgrades on strength, speed, stamina, dexterity, reflex and intelligence?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrades increase the maximal stats a horse can achieve with training.